# Why Do I Need to Use Custom Session Manager?

Tags: c#, session

First of all, forgive my silly question. I am new to ASP.net and C#. When I googled to understand session in asp.net, i stumbled upon many discussion on "Custom Session Manager".

Why Do I Need to Use Custom Session Manager? Can I just use the session like the example below?

```
//Default.aspx

Session["name"] = "My Name";
```

then

```
//NextPage.aspx

Label1.Text = "Hello" + (string)Session["name"];
```

Comment: `lyas` shouldn't that be `Session["name"] = "My Name";` also instead of using the `+` why not use string.Join() method check your syntax

Comment: Aha.. I just type without checking the syntax. That's not my question/problem. I want to know if it is possible just to ignore all that 'custom session manager' thing.

Comment: that's perfectly fine the way that you are accessing / assigning the values less the incorrect syntax lol

Comment: @DJKRAZE using `+` for concatenation is acceptable. `String.Join` only makes sense if you've got lots of strings, besides it's just an example code.

Comment: Oh, and you're using `'` (for `chars`) instead of `"` (for `string`s).

Comment: Wow, so fast. Too bad I can only accept an answer after two minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a "Custom session manager" - I've been working with ASP.NET for almost 10 years now and never come across that term before.

Your example use of `Session` is acceptable (although the call to `.ToString()` isn't *that* necessary, you can cast it directly to `String` which guards against null values).

Generally speaking, you only need to worry yourself about `Session` if you're working on a multi-server webfarm or load-balanced cluster.

Answer (score 3):

A different session manager could be used to change the behavior of where session is stored whether in memory, to a file or a database.

Comment: If only I can accept two answers. The one I accept directly answer my question. Your answer does give me some knowledge. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you need to create a class called Session Manager to manage all that information traveling between your application screens.

Many times these variables are used in a Wizard, or any processes that the end is right and necessary that such information be removed or amended. In this way you can do it by groups of objects or variables.

My suggestion is to create it and use wisely (remember you're using server's (iis) memory)

idea sample:

```
public class SessionManager
{
    //Groups of variables
    public enum Groups
    {
        Users,
        Processes
    }

    //Value keys
    private static int USERID
    {
        get { return USERID"; }
    }

    private static string USERGUID
    {
        get { return "USERGUID"; }
    }

    //Properties        
    public String UserGuid
    {
        get { return this.session[USERGUID]; }
        set { this.session[USERGUID] = value; }
    }

...

    //Finnish using values
    public bool Finnish(Groups group)
    {
        switch (group)
        {
            case Groups.Users:
                this.Session.Remove(USERID);
                this.Session.Remove(USERGUID);
                break;
            case Groups.Processes:
                this.Session.Remove(UP);
                this.Session.Remove(DOWN);
            default:
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

...

}
```

Hope this helps!